# HID "report descriptor" includes set/get features?

Tags: usb, usb-host, hid

After reading about HID report descriptor, it seems that it only includes "input report".

http://www.rennes.supelec.fr/ren/fi/elec/docs/usb/hid1_11.pdf

But what about get/set features ? Why it is not part of it ?

Thank you

Comment: HID supports both input and output reports. For example check on HID1_11.pdf page 70 E.6 Report Descriptor (Keyboard), which shows an example USB Keyboard HID descriptor -- there is an Input(Data,Variable,Absolute) for the modifier byte, an Output(Data,Variable,Absolute) for the LED indicators (caps lock, num lock, etc.), and an Input(Data,Array) for the scan codes Key array.

Comment: Thanks I try to undertstand what is included in report descriptor

Answer (score 1):

Get/Set features are elements of standard (default) control pipe and are common for all USB classes. That't why they are not mentioned in the particular device class specifications.

Comment: But doesn't the host need to know the structure of a device specific get and set feature messeges? If yes how can host know it if it is not mentioned in report descriptor?

Comment: @ransh, the device structure/class/etc is reported in initial  inquiry in the process of device enumeration, GET_DESCRIPTOR. The rest follows/unfolds depending on descriptor.